# RegEx parsing email address checking for quality

Tags: regex

I'm very new to regex, reading and learning but need some direction

I need to parse email addresses for quality

fax=1AreaCodeNumber@domain.com
or 1AreaCodeNumber@doamin.com

need to ensure the 1AreaCodeNumber is 10 digits only, must start with 1
If it is 9 digits, and the first number is not a 1 add the 1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What language are you working in for this?

Answer (score 0):

`1?\d{9}` will match a 1 followed by 9 digits, or 9 digits without the 1. The full regex would be `(fax=)?1?\d{9}@domain.com`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
const regex = /^(1?)\d{9}@(domain\.com|doamin\.com)/;
str = `1123456879@domain.com`;
let m;

if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    if(m[1] === '') {
       str = '1' + str;
    }

    console.log('matched: ' + str); 
} else {
    console.log('No Match');
}
```